# How use null in float field(null acceptable) with mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to put null value infloat field with cur.execute

```
cur = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
sql = insert into mytable(id,mydata) VALUE(%s,%s)
data = ('test','Null') 
cur.execute(sql,data)
```

However it shows error like this.

```
Data truncated for column 'mydata' at row 1
```

I guess it is because of NULL value but, how can I use NULL in python ???
If I use `nan` instead it shows error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent for NULL in python is None. Please try using None instead of Null in the data variable.

Comment: I wrongly thought `nan` is null for python. It is null for Pandas. Thank you very much.